# Simple_Form --Bootstrap rails - Could not find generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am running rails 4.2.0 and ruby 2.2.1p85  i keep getting the below error when trying to generate simple_form.  any ideas?

```
justin@justin-ThinkPad-T60:~/workspaces/gigitt$ rails g simple_form:install --bootstrap
Could not find generator 'simple_form:install'. Maybe you meant 'responders:install' or 'devise:install' or 'integration_test'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
justin@justin-ThinkPad-T60:~/workspaces/gigitt$
```

Here is a copy of my:

Gemfile: http://pastebin.com/csVtdW1m Gemfile.lock: http://pastebin.com/csi20pqP

Comment: `simple_form` gem is in your `Gemfile`?do you already run `bundle install`?

Comment: yes, simple_form is in my Gemfile.  it is using simple form 3.1.0  i ran bundle install, it shows as using 3.1.0 but still no dice.

Comment: if you ran `bundle exec rails generate` do you see `simple form` generators ?

Comment: I see the following: http://pastebin.com/LhsYKuKS

Comment: please post result of `bundle exec rails generate` to the question body not in comment.

Comment: i have not see simple form generators. Please post your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` in to the questions body.

Comment: Posted. Any feedback is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: all looks good, it is works for me, try create new app for test this case. I pretty sure missing something.

Comment: yeah, just tested it by creating a new app and it worked perfectly.  not sure what was wrong with my previous build.  thanks a lot though

Comment: can i post last comment as answer?